# Let $f$ be a cont. on $\mathbb{R}$ and define $G(x)=\int_0^{\sin (x)}f(t) dt $. Show that $G$ is differentiable on $\Bbb{R}$ and compute $G'$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and define
> $$G(x)=\int_0^{\sin (x)}f(t) dt $$ Show that $G$ is differentiable on
> $\mathbb{R}$ and compute $G'$.

This is an exercise from [Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus by Kenneth A. Ross](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Elementary_Analysis.html?id=5JxHZNpMq3AC&redir_esc=y).

My first idea is the following. Let $x\in \Bbb R$. Define $F(x):=\displaystyle\int_0^{x}f(t) dt $. And prove that $G:=F\circ \sin$ is differentiable at $x$ using:

[image]

It is clear that $\sin(x)$ is differentiable at $x$. So I need to proof that $F$ is differentiable at $y:=\sin(x)$. I was trying to prove that using:

> **34.3 Fundamental Theorem of Calculus II.**
>
> Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[a, b] .$ For $x$ in $[a, b],$ let
> $$
> F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t) d t
> $$
> Then $F$ is continuous on $[a, b] .$ If $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ in $(a, b),$ then $F$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$ and
> $$
> F^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)=f\left(x_{0}\right)
> $$

I'm not sure if I can use this theorem. Obviously, $f$ sattisfies the conditions. But as $y=\sin(x) \in [-1,1]$, I dont see how I could choose $a,b$ in theorem 34.3, such that it fits this case. It seems clear that I should choose $a:=0$, and if $y>0$ I could choose $b:=1$, but if $y<0$, I can't find any $b$ such that $y\in[a,b]$.

---

I wanted to know if I'm heading in the right direction, so I looked at the official solution manual. What they are doing there seems complete nonsense to me:

[image]

I don't see why they are doing what they are doing. They end the proof with $G$ is continuous. Why is that result needed ? And isn't $f$ confused for (some undefined) $F$ in the beginning?

---

As this proof didn't satisfy me, I looked further, and I found this proof:

[image]

This proof seems completely solid to me. But it is much less intuitive (for me). I wouldn't have come with this proof myself.

My question are:

1. Was I heading in the right direction with my first idea ? Or is it not possible to apply theorem 34.3 in this kind of way ?
2. Am I right that the official solution manual is complete nonsense, or am I missing something ?
3. Is this last proof I found correct, and do you think the author of the book has this kind of proof in mind when he wrote this exercise ? Or do you think the author was expecting some other kind of proof ?

Edit: For the bounty I would like to see a rigorous prove of why $G$ is differentiable on all $x\in \Bbb R$ using only theorems that are proven in [Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus by Kenneth A. Ross](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Elementary_Analysis.html?id=5JxHZNpMq3AC&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Oh, haha, will I didn't meant to add a 300 point bounty, don't know what happened, I thought I had selected a 50 point bounty. Anyway, you better give some well thought answer for 300 points ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
G(x)
&=F(\sin(x))\\
&=\int_0^{\sin(x)}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
F(u)
&=\int_0^uf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\underbrace{\int_{-1}^uf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}_{\substack{\text{differentiable}\\\text{for $u\ge-1$}}}-\underbrace{\int_{-1}^0f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}_\text{constant}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says
$$
F'(u)=f(u)\tag{3}
$$
The Chain Rule says that
$$
\begin{align}
G'(x)
&=F'(\sin(x))\cos(x)\\
&=f(\sin(x))\cos(x)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

**Technical Point:** To apply Theorem 28.4 to Theorem 34.3 without any further work, we should choose the lower bound of integration in $(2)$ to be lower than $-1$.

However, with a bit of extra work, we can show that $f$ need only be continuous on $[-1,1]$. The only problem arises when computing $F'(\pm1)$. Since $F(u)$ will only see $u\in[-1,1]$, we only need to consider the one-sided derivative at $\pm1$.

Suppose $u_0=\pm1$, then for $u\in(-1,1)$ we can apply the Mean Value Theorem to find a $\xi$ between $u_0$ and $u$, hence in $(-1,1)$, so that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{F(u)-F(u_0)}{u-u_0}
&=F'(\xi)\\
&=f(\xi)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, we have the one-sided derivative
$$
\begin{align}
F'(u_0)
&=\lim_{u\to u_0}\frac{F(u)-F(u_0)}{u-u_0}\\
&=\lim_{\xi\to u_0}f(\xi)\\
&=f(u_0)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

---

1. You are thinking correctly about applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Chain Rule.
2. I am not sure why they are showing that $G$ is continuous. Since they have shown its derivative exists, it is already continuous.
3. The handwritten proof looks okay. It is a different approach, but it is valid. You don't need the Chain Rule with that approach.

Comment: Okay, but we need to prove this for all $x\in \Bbb R$. So $u=\sin x \in [-1,1]$. So if you look at theorem 34.3 very litterally, then it seems like you can't use it. You have to choose $a=0$. But $u$ could be less than zero. I thought that may be the reason why the handwritten prove uses this other technique.

Comment: What "this" do we need to prove that we haven't? The fact that $u\in[-1,1]$ simply means we only need to know $f(t)$ on $[-1,1]$. Please clarify your concern.

Comment: I mean proving that $G$ is differentiable on all $x\in \Bbb R$. To prove that you need that show that $F$ is differentiable on $u\in[-1,1]$. You say that you can use theorem 34.3 (see my post for an attached picture) for that. But this theorem proves only that $u\in(a,b)$ is differentiable. Where you have chosen $a$ to be $0$ it seems.

Comment: If it helps to put @robjohn 's comment another way, we already know that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, so $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ does everything the fundamental theorem promises all over $\mathbb{R}$. We also know $\sin(x)$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and, since $G(x)=F(\sin(x))$ we have a composition of differentiable functions (so it's differentiable).

Comment: @Trold But if interpret the fundamental theorem very litterally as stated in my book, it promises only that $x\in(0,b)$ where $b\in\Bbb R$ are differentiable. While we also need nonpositive values of $x$ to be differentiable, right ?

Comment: Have you covered properties of limits of integration yet? It's perfectly fine to write, e.g., $\int_0^{-1}f(t)dt$ (It's not hard to prove from the definition of an integral that it's $-\int_{-1}^0f(t)dt$.) If you wanted to follow your book that literally, you could always tackle the positive cases of $x$ with $\int_0^x f(t)dt$ and the negative cases with a different interval, say $[x-1,0]$ and $\int_x^0f(t)$ then observe that this is just $-F(x)$ and therefore $F$ is also continuous, differentiable, etc. etc. at these negative $x$.

Comment: @Trold Yeah, that is bothering me, and I think that is also the reason that the handwritten proof (and maybe also the official solution) doesn't go the easy route. But I'm not sure, that is my question ;) I know how to show that: $\int_a^bh(x)dx=-\int_b^ah(x)dx$. But still, the theorem is talking about intervals $(0,b)$ to be differentiable, not intervals $(b,0)$. Taking $b$ to be negative seem therefore meaningless to me. How do I show that I can take intervals $(b,0)$ as well ? And what about $0$ ?

Comment: (Also, apologies, I totally rewrote my comment to what I hoped might be a more satisfactory explanation and apparently wasn't quick enough.)

Comment: @Trold No worries. Just trying to make sure the comments are still in the right chronological order. I've covered properties of limits of integration btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17697/discussion-between-kasper-and-trold).

Comment: @Kasper: I now understand your concern with Theorem 34.3, and I have added a bit to show that it still applies.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks ! That seem to solve my concerns. One final note, shouldn't you choose $a=-2$ or $a=-1-\epsilon$ as Theorem 34.3 seems to talk about differentiability in $(a,b)$ and not $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Kasper: to apply Theorem 34.3 as given, yes. However, I have added an argument to show that we get the same result even if we only know that $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @robjohn awesome, thanks, learned a lot from you